# Errors when deploying Liferay 6.0.6 on Glassfish 3.1.1

Tags: java, glassfish, liferay, portlet, portal

I'm trying to deploy Liferay 6.0.6 on an already existing Glassfish 3.1.1 installation. I have followed the Liferay Administration Guide perfectly and while I can deploy the war, it doesn't do it right.

Here is how the log looks when I deploy:

> [#|2011-11-10T11:32:33.056+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=95;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(2);|PWC4011:
>   Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context ,
>   because request parameters have already been read, or
>   ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:32:33.295+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=95;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(2);|GUI
>   deployment: uploadToTempfile|#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:32:33.296+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=95;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(2);|uploadFileName=liferay-portal-6.0.6-20110225.war|#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:33:22.456+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|DPL8029:
>   Ignore WEB-INF/weblogic.xml in archive
>   /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/liferay-portal-6.0.6-20110225/,
>   as Sun counterpart runtime xml WEB-INF/sun-web.xml is present in the
>   same archive.|#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:33:29.943+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|Loading
>   file:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated/jsp/liferay-portal-6.0.6-20110225/loader_1278430715/system.properties|#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:33:30.016+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ServerDetector|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|Detected
>   server glassfish|#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:33:30.983+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|PWC1412:
>   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring root
>   WebApplicationContext|#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:33:31.870+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|Loading
>   file:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated/jsp/liferay-portal-6.0.6-20110225/loader_1278430715/portal.properties|#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:33:31.875+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|Loading
>   file:/opt/glassfish3/portal-ext.properties|#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:33:49.221+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:33:49,216
>   INFO  [DialectDetector:69] Determining dialect for MySQL 5 |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:33:49.372+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:33:49,371
>   INFO  [DialectDetector:49] Using dialect
>   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:00.355+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:00,353
>   INFO  [PortalImpl:278] Global lib directory
>   /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:00.359+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:00,358
>   INFO  [PortalImpl:298] Portal lib directory
>   /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/liferay-portal-6.0.6-20110225/WEB-INF/lib/
>   |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:33.814+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.security|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|No
>   Principals mapped to Role [users].|#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:35.399+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|Starting
>   Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.0.6 CE (Bunyan / Build 6006 /
>   February 17, 2011)|#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:36.828+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;*ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:36,826
>   ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter:101] Table 'lportal.lock*' doesn't exist
>   |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:38.636+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;*ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:38,634
>   WARN  [ReleaseLocalServiceImpl:143] Table 'lportal.release*' doesn't
>   exist |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:38.639+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:38,638
>   INFO  [ReleaseLocalServiceImpl:84] Create tables and populate with
>   default data |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:45.846+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:45,843
>   INFO  [BaseDB:403] Database does not support case sensitive queries
>   |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:46.989+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:46,988
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyProcessSuite |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:46.998+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:46,997
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyProperties |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:47.000+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:46,999
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyMySQL |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:47.480+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:47,478
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyCounter |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:47.533+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:47,532
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyUUID |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:47.542+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:47,541
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyRole |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:47.549+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:47,548
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyBlogs |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:47.877+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:47,876
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyBookmarks |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:47.886+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:47,885
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyCalendar |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:47.896+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:47,895
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyDocumentLibrary |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:47.923+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:47,922
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyGroup |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:48.112+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:48,110
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyImageGallery |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:48.123+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:48,122
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyJournal |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:48.153+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:48,152
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyLayout |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:48.167+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:48,166
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyMessageBoards |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:48.223+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:48,222
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyOrganization |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:48.225+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:48,224
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifySocial |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:48.226+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:48,225
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyUser |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:34:48.263+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:34:48,262
>   INFO  [VerifyProcess:76] Verifying
>   com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyWiki |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:35:01.518+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=269;_ThreadName=liferay/scheduler_dispatch;|11:35:01,516
>   INFO  [PluginPackageUtil:1109] Reloading repositories |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:35:07.971+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:35:07,968
>   INFO  [HotDeployUtil:69] Initializing hot deploy manager 774754992 |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:35:08.340+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|11:35:08,339
>   INFO  [AutoDeployDir:105] Auto deploy scanner started for
>   /opt/glassfish3/deploy |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:35:12.198+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=269;_ThreadName=liferay/scheduler_dispatch;|11:35:12,197
>   ERROR [PluginPackageUtil:1127] Unable to load repository
>   http://plugins.liferay.com/official
>   com.liferay.portal.plugin.PluginPackageException: Unable to
>   communicate with repository http://plugins.liferay.com/official |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:35:15.485+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|WEB0671:
>   Loading application [liferay-portal-6.0.6-20110225] at
>   [/liferay-portal-6.0.6-20110225]|#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:35:22.224+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=269;_ThreadName=liferay/scheduler_dispatch;|11:35:22,223
>   ERROR [PluginPackageUtil:1127] Unable to load repository
>   http://plugins.liferay.com/community
>   com.liferay.portal.plugin.PluginPackageException: Unable to
>   communicate with repository http://plugins.liferay.com/community |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:35:32.264+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=269;_ThreadName=liferay/scheduler_dispatch;|11:35:32,263
>   WARN  [PluginPackageUtil:312] Unable to communicate with repository
>   http://plugins.liferay.com/official |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:35:35.276+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(4);|liferay-portal-6.0.6-20110225
>   was successfully deployed in 181,927 milliseconds.|#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:35:42.286+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=269;_ThreadName=liferay/scheduler_dispatch;|11:35:42,285
>   WARN  [PluginPackageUtil:312] Unable to communicate with repository
>   http://plugins.liferay.com/community |#]

I changed the "lower_case_table_names" to 1 in my MySQL in Linux and still get: [BaseDB:403] Database does not support case sensitive queries

This is what the log says when I open Liferay after deploying the liferay war:

> [#|2011-11-10T11:38:44.604+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=141;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8080(1);|11:38:44,602
>   INFO  [PortalImpl:3829] Current URL /liferay-portal-6.0.6-20110225/
>   generates exception: null |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:38:44.606+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=141;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8080(1);|11:38:44,605
>   INFO  [PortalImpl:3841] |#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:39:15.550+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet|_ThreadID=145;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8080(5);|PWC6117:
>   File
>   "%2Fopt%2Fglassfish3%2Fglassfish%2Fdomains%2Fdomain1%2Fdocroot%2Fhtml%2Fportal%2Fcss.jsp"
>   not found|#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:39:15.556+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet|_ThreadID=143;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8080(3);|PWC6117:
>   File
>   "%2Fopt%2Fglassfish3%2Fglassfish%2Fdomains%2Fdomain1%2Fdocroot%2Fhtml%2Fportlet%2Flogin%2Fcss%2Fmain.jsp"
>   not found|#]
>
> [#|2011-11-10T11:39:15.565+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet|_ThreadID=142;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8080(2);|PWC6117:
>   File
>   "%2Fopt%2Fglassfish3%2Fglassfish%2Fdomains%2Fdomain1%2Fdocroot%2Fhtml%2Fjs%2Fbarebone.jsp"
>   not found|#]

And here is a screen of what the deployed liferay looks like:

[image: This is how it looks]

Any ideas on what might have gone wrong?

Comment: "Database does not support case sensitive queries" is just an info, no action is needed. First log excerpt is completely ok and not relevant to your problem. Can you share java stack trace?

Comment: Thanks. There is not stack trace in glassfish server.log, or do you mean from somewhere else?

Comment: I don't use glassfish so I don't know weather there are separate log files for server and applications. Try to find are there other log files.

Comment: server.log seems to be the one. Any exception from liferay should be there. The above is what I got when I deployed and then when I visited the start page.

Comment: Any update here? Have you been able to figure out why the pages aren't loading?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you would have solved this problem. But I am writing this post so that it may help others.

Even I faced this issue, this seems to be Glassfish related issue rather than Liferay related when you deploy the war file through Glassfish UI admin console. You won't see this problem when you deploy as below using glassfish command line deploy commands:

1. first rename the downloaded war file to liferay-portal.war and
2. then,

   bash:- asadmin deploy --contextroot "/" liferay-portal.war

This has solved the problem for me.

HTH,
Sharana